# Where should I put a script to put my monitor into standby?

Tags: scripts, suspend, hdmi, gdm, systemd-logind

Acquired a great Samsung HDMI TV/monitor that doesn't go into standby when the signal is dropped.  I've acquired a Pulse Eight CEC command injector, and worked out how to turn the monitor off/on from the command line.

The problem is that I don't know where the most reliable/future proof/Ubuntu/Gnome way of causing those commands to execute is - What I've looked into so far:

#### systemd

Seems to have targets for when a user is logged in, and for when the graphical system comes up, but not before the login.

#### acpid

Catching the screen sleep/wake mechanism here sounds perfect, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

#### gdm3

Seems to support adding scripts in just about every case OTHER than on keyboard activity.

#### xss-lock

Tried using this with a script to sleep the monitor when it runs, and catch the SIGHUP to issue a wake command - but it didn't seem to work reliably.

---

I found this from 2015:
[How to run scripts on screen sleep / wake](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573552/how-to-run-scripts-on-screen-sleep-wake)

... but just about every option above feels like a better solution than looping a background task to scrape log traffic constantly or takes @wait/2 seconds to come up after a key is pressed.  Is that the best solution available?

Comment: Do you want to turn off your screen or put your computer to sleep?

Comment: Turn the screen off.  The computer needs to stay on.

Comment: How do you want to turn it off? pressing a key combination? if so ... keyboard shortcuts. In the command section of keyboard shortcuts  you can add a script to execute. seems by far the easiest method to me ;-)

Comment: Can you clarify? For example there is a hint that you want the HDMI screen to blank when no one is logged on. Is this a laptop you put to sleep? Is there a time out period of inactivity when you want one or more monitors to go into standby but another monitor (like laptop display) to stay on? The four or five references to different methods is probably confusing me...

Comment: It's a TV I'm using as an external monitor for a desktop - A "Samsung 40NU7100 Flat 40” 4K UHD 7 Series Smart TV 2018" to be exact. 

I would like the TV to turn off the same way the last TV I used in this fashion did.  I get up and walk away for more than a few minutes, and it goes into standby.  I come back and move the mouse and the TV turns on.  The problem is that this television set puts up (and leaves up) a screen like this when the normal 'screen blanking' kicks in:
https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/50843i8ED953BEAA77539D/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999

Answer (score 1):

I use below script to turn off the screen after 1 minute of idleness.
Code doesn't belong to me, I just modified it to my needs

You need to install `xprintidle`

```
sudo apt install xprintidle
cd ~
mkdir myscripts
cd myscripts
```

copy and paste the below code into terminal to create a bash script

```
cat>turnoffscreen.sh<<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
# Wanted trigger timeout in milliseconds.
IDLE_TIME=$((1*60*1000))
IDLE_WARN=$((((1*60*1000))-((10000))))
# Sequence to execute when timeout triggers.
trigger_cmd() {

   # put your code here, the below command just an example
   xset s blank ; sleep 1 ; xset s activate 

}

sleep_time=$IDLE_TIME
triggered=false

# ceil() instead of floor()
while sleep $(((sleep_time+999)/1000)); do
    idle=$(xprintidle)

if [ $idle -ge $IDLE_WARN ]; then
    notify-send --icon=info "Turning off the screen ..."
    sleep 10
    idle_check=$(xprintidle)
       if [ $idle_check -ge $idle  ]; then
        if ! $triggered; then
                 trigger_cmd
                 triggered=true
                 sleep_time=$IDLE_TIME
        fi
     fi


    else

        triggered=false

        # Give 100 ms buffer to avoid frantic loops shortly before triggers.
        sleep_time=$((IDLE_TIME-idle+100))
    fi
done
EOF
```

then make it executable

```
chmod +x turnoffscreen.sh
```

Add it to startup applications list

```
gnome-session-properties
```